# Denied Message on Startup

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

One user of my app reports that he gets a denied message everytime he opens the app. Reinstall and start with fresh data didn't work. I can't reproduce it and I don't throw the message by myself. Does anyone have any experience with something like this?

EDIT:

This Screenshot send me the user:
[image]

Maybe this is a problem with the Live SDK. I got these Error messages in my logs, although I'm not sure they are related:

```
Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectExceptionThe URL contains the resource 'files', which isn't supported.
```

And:

```
System.ArgumentExceptionpath
Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectClient.GetApiOperation(String path, ApiMethod method, String body)
Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectClient.GetAsync(String path)
```

Strange is that it seems to work for a whole lot of users.

thanks for your help.

Regards

Comment: What kind of denied message do you mean? Your user could at least send you a screenshot. It's hard to judge without anything visual..

Comment: It's really just a message "denied". I added a screenshot.

Comment: If possible, request your users to send event logs for more info.

Comment: Everything I log goes directly to bugsense. But I can't find something related to it.